# Getting an error while using a string array in go struct

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have couple of struct types in my application and some of them have struct arrays as attribute like :

```
type A struct {
...
B String_Array    `json:"item" gorm:"type:text"`
...
}

type String_Array []string
```

item is an array (I am fetching it through an API request)

```
{
...,
"item":["elem1","elem2"],
...
}
```

When I try to use

```
var a []A
result := db.Find(&a)
print("Total Records %d", a.RowsAffected)
```

I have aux scan and value functions like below:

```
func (p *String_Array) Scan(src any) error {
    bytes, ok := src.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("src value cannot cast to []byte")
    }
    *p = strings.Split(string(bytes), ",")
    return nil
}

func (p String_Array) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if len(p) == 0 {
        return nil, nil
    }
    return strings.Join(p, ","), nil
}
```

I get multiple

sql: Scan error on column index 4, name "item": src value cannot cast to []byte

Even though I got those errors, it also prints the count as :

```
Total Records %d264%
```

I am not sure why gorm throws above error messages.

**Update:** B sometimes does not exist, I also tried to have:

B *String_Array    `json:"item" gorm:"type:text"`

It didn't work, I still get the same errors

**Update 2:**
In case somebody might have the same problem, I've solved it by modifying the scanner function as below:

```
func (p *String_Array) Scan(src any) error {
    if strings.Contains(src.(string), ",") {
        *p = strings.Split(src.(string), ",")
        return nil
    } else {
        *p = []string{src.(string)}
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: `String_array` is a new type. You need to write a custom scanner for that type so that GORM can handle it.

Comment: I have them actually:



seems there is a problem in scanning function. Thanks for reminding ...